# Amazon Linux EC2 instance unreachable - Volume Read Jumped

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I'm running an Apache web server on an EC2 Amazon Linux instance.  The server was unreachable (timeouts) this morning, both via SSH and through the website.  I had to reboot the server and then I was able to connect via SSH, restart Apache and then I was back online.  This has happened previously as well.

*CPU utilization jumped from average 2% to 10% through the downtime.
*CPU Credit balance was full the entire time
*Memory was fine the entire time.
*Volume disk read jumped up abnormally high.

What can I do to troubleshoot what was trying to read so much data from the disk?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use lsof or iotop for starters. Later on you might want to try some monitoring tool like Zabbix or Prometheus.